# In calculus of variation: why are minimizing sequences bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Assume the usual variational setting: Let $\mathcal{A} \subset W^{1,q}$ be the set of admissible functions and \begin{equation} I: \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R} \end{equation} the functional that needs to be minimized. One then chooses a minimizing sequence $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. \begin{equation} I[u_k] \to \inf_{w \in \mathcal{A}} I[w]. \end{equation}

The next step is to show that the minimizing sequence is bounded, so one can show that it converges in the weak topology. My question is:

> Assuming you are able to verify that $I[u_k]$ is uniformly bounded for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, how can you show that $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $W^{1,q}$.

This step seams trivial, as it is frequently omitted in the books I read. Yet, I can't produce a proof for that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the "usual" setting, the property you are missing is often added as a requirement for $I$. One requires that $I[w] \to \infty$ for $\|w\|_{1,q} \to \infty$.

Comment: @martini: Thank you. But in my specific case I have \begin{equation} I[u]=\frac{1}{2} \int_{U} \vert \nabla u \vert^2+\frac{1}{4} \int_U (1-\vert u \vert^2)^2 \end{equation} and $\mathcal{A}=H^1(U)$. I don't see why (assuming the opposite) the unboundedness of $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $H^1(U)$ implies that $I[u_k]$ is not uniformly bounded. Do you?

Comment: @martini: by the way: If you post your comment as an answer (maybe mention coercivity), I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Martini has pointed out in the comments, the property you need is coercivity. Indeed, if you assume that your function is coercive , then any minimizing sequence must be bounded, because if not, then $I[u_n]\to\infty$ by coerciviness.

It is important to note that only coerciviness does not guarantee that you functional can be minimized, as this [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287475/continuous-coercive-functional-not-bounded-below) shows.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $I[u]\geq F(|u|_{W^{1,q}})$ for some $F:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ non-decreasing such that $F(0)=0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} F(t)=\infty$. In your specific case, this is possible if $q=2$ and $W^{1,q}=H^1$.