# Why is functional analysis so obsessed with sequences?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

Beginning functional analysis I thought I would learn about generalized properties of functions and operators but yet I am flipping through pages after pages of texts on cauchy sequence, convergence, etc.

What is the purpose of learning about sequences in functional analysis? Seems rather pointless to me as I have already learned about sequences in elementary calculus

Comment: Local enumerable basis is the answer. If you want to study more general spaces, look at topological vector spaces.

Comment: I would say that one good definition of Calculus is that it is the study of limits and limiting processes. As such, sequences play a pivotal role in everything that you'll do in Analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences are a fundamental way of probing topological spaces in general, e.g. in investigating whether a given set is compact, a question which is of interest in functional analysis (see the [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem), and also the thread [Why is compactness so important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485822/264)). However, you'll also find many presentations of functional analysis that instead use a generalization of the notion of sequence, called a "net" ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))).