# Continuous function on compact metric space attains maximum value, intuition?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a question here on a proposition from a real analysis textbook.

> If $K$ is compact metric space and $f$ is continuous on $K$ (here $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$), then there exists $x'$ such that $f(x') = \sup_{x \in K} f(x)$, i.e. $f$ takes on its maximum value.

Here is the proof.

> Let $M = \sup_{x \in K} f(x)$ and suppose $f(x) < M$ for every point in $K$. If $y \in K$, let $L_y = (f(y) + M)/2$ and let $\epsilon_y = (M - f(y))/2$. By the continuity of $f$, there exists $\delta_y$ such that $|f(z) - f(y)| < \epsilon_y$ if $d(z, y) < \delta_y$. then $G_y = B(y, \delta_y)$ is an open ball containing $y$ on which $f$ is bounded above by $L_y$. Now $\{G_y\}_{y \in K}$ is an open cover for $K$. Let $\{G_{y_1}, \ldots, G_{y_n}\}$ be a finite subcover. Let $L = \max(L_{y_1}, \ldots, L_{y_n})$. Then $L$ is strictly smaller than $M$. If $x \in K$, then $x$ will be in some one of the $G_{y_i}$, and hence $f(x) \le L_{y_i} \le L$. But this says that $L$ is an upper bound for $\{f(x): x \in K\}$, a contradiction to the definition of $M$. Therefore our supposition that $f(x) < M$ for every $x$ in $K$ cannot be true.

I can follow the proof step to step, but I'm interested in the following: if I were to distill this proof down to its essential idea(s), what would they be? What is the intuition behind the proof of this proposition?

Comment: The proof is most clear in my head as follows, in general topological spaces it is the case that the continuous image of a compact set is compact, i.e if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and X is compact, then $f(X):=\{y \in Y: \exists x \in X, f(x)=y\}$ is compact as well. This is most easily shown from the open-cover definition of compactness (it's basically immediate). Then if you know Heine-Borel, that compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded, you have the result without much computation.

Answer (score 7):

The key ideas are (1) if $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is compact and (2) compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded (so the infimum and supremum exist) and closed (so the set contains its infimum and supremum).

Applying (2) to the compact subset $f(X)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ shows that $f(X)$ has a maximum and minimum, i.e. that $f$ attains its max and min.

Comment: Those are not the key ideas of the proof given however.

Comment: Let me be clear: What you wrote is a better route to this result IMO. However, the OP asked for help understanding the intution behind the proof presented. (I don't like the given proof btw)

Comment: I'd say that the proof given is implicitly using both of the facts I stated.

Comment: I agree that the proof given is implicitly using the facts stated in this answer. In fact, it looks to me as if the proof given was concocted by deconstructing the usual proof that the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: The given proof looks completely unintuitive to me, while this answer here seems the soul of intuitiveness.

Answer (score 1):

I think the current proof is intuitive enough. Its actually quite graphic, but we may make it more verbal, so one may visualise it even more easily.

Let us say that a set $A$ is *separated* or *bounded away* from an upper bound $M$ if there exists a clear gap between it and $M$; that is, if there exists a number $s$ such that $a<s<M$ for every $a\in A$.

Now, intuitively, what the proof says is this:

- If the supremum $M$ is not attainable, then $f(y)<M$ for each $y\in K$.
- Since $f$ is continuous, we can always grow from each $y\in K$ a sufficiently small open ball $G_y$ whose image $f(G_y)$ is separated from $M$.
- As each $G_y$ is centred at $y$, the union of these balls covers $K$.
- It follows from the compactness of $K$ that we can pick a finite cover $G_{y_1},\ldots,G_{y_n}$ of it.
- As each $f(G_{y_k})$ is separated from $M$, so is their **finite** union $\bigcup_{k=1}^n f(G_{y_k})$. (The finiteness is essential here. See also [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/485856) of "Why is compactness so important?")
- In turn, $f(K)\subseteq f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n G_{y_k}\right)=\bigcup_{k=1}^n f(G_{y_k})$ is separated from $M$ too.
- But this is a contradiction, because $M$ is the supremum of $f(K)$ and the supremum of a set, by definition, cannot be separated from the underlying set.
- Therefore the supremum $M$ must be attainable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the given proof is flawed since it is tacitly assumed that $M<\infty$.

Nevertheless, the key idea is the following: If $f(y)<M$ for all $y\in K$, then you can choose for each point $y\in K$ a number $L_y$ with $f(y)<L_y<M$, and then by continuity a small open neighborhood $G_y$ of $y$ such that $f(x)\leq L_y$ for all $x\in G_y$.

The family $\bigl (G_y\bigr)_{y\in X}$ is an open cover of $X$. Since $K$ is compact we can select a finite subfamily $\bigl(G_{y_k}\bigr)_{1\leq k\leq N}$ in such a way that the $G_{y_k}$ already cover all of $K$.

Now the bounds $L_y$ come in: Put $\max_{1\leq k\leq N} L_{y_k}=:L$. I claim that $f(x)\leq L$ for all $x\in K$, in other words: $L$ is an upper bound of the set $\{f(x)\,|\,x\in K\}$. – *Proof:* Given any $x\in K$ this point $x$ is contained in one of the selected $G_{y_k}$. It follows that $f(x)\leq L_{y_k}\leq L$.

On the other hand   $L<M$ since each of the *finitely many* $L_{y_k}$ is $<M$. This contradicts the definition of $M$. It follows that our working assumption "$f(y)<M$ for all $y$" cannot be upheld.

Answer (score 0):

The result is valid for any non-empty space $ X $ with the compactness property. And a previous answer points out that a proof by contradiction cannot start by assuming $\infty\ne M=\sup \{f(x):x\in X\}.$

Whether $M$ is finite or not, the main idea is that if $f(x)\ne M$ for every $x\in X,$ then for every $x\in X$ there is a bounded open real subset $U(x)$ such that $f(x)\in U(x)$ and $M>\max \overline {U(x)}.$ Note that $\{f(y):y\in f^{-1}U(x)\}\subset U(x)$ because $f$ is a function. So we have $$\sup \{f(y):y\in f^{-1}U(x)\}\leq \sup U(x)=\max \overline {U(x)}<M.$$

Now if $\{f^{-1}U(x_j):j=1,...,n\}$ is a finite sub-cover of the open cover $\{f^{-1}U(x): x\in X\} $  then the contradiction is $M=\sup \{f(x):x\in X\}=\max_{j=1,...,n}\sup\{f(y):y\in f^{-1}U(x_j)\}\leq \max_{j=1,...,n}\max \overline {U(x_j)}<M.$ (Because $\{\max \overline {U(x_i)}\}_{j=1,...,n}$  is a finite set of reals, each less than $M.$)

Remark: Any statement about open sets has a corresponding dual statement about their complements, the closed sets.

When $F$ is a family of subsets of $X$ we say $F$ has the Finite Intersection Property (FIP) to mean that any finite non-empty $G\subset F$ satisfies  $\cap G\ne \emptyset.$

If a space is compact then any non-empty family $F$ of closed subsets of $X$ that has the FIP satisfies $\cap F\ne \emptyset.$ Otherwise $\{X$ \ $s : s\in F\}$ is an open cover with no finite sub-cover. (The converse also holds.)

Now if $X$  is  non-empty and compact , and if the continuous $f:X\to \mathbb R $ does not attain its maximum, then with $M$ as above, $f^{-1}[r,M)$ is not empty and is closed in $X$ for every $r<M$.  (Its complement in $X$ is  $f^{-1}(-\infty,r)$ because  $y\in X \implies f(y)<M.$)

But if $G=\{f^{-1}[r_j,M)\}_{j=1,...,n}\subset F=\{f^{-1}[r,M):r<M\}$ then with $r=\max_{j=1,...,n}r_j$ we have $\cap G=f^{-1}[r,M)\ne \emptyset.$  So $F$ is a non-empty family of closed subsets of $X$, and $F$ has the FIP . But $\cap F=\emptyset,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I note about this proof is it presumes $f(K)$ is bounded and a $\sup_{x\in K} f(x)$ exists and states so without proof.  So that is *not* one of key points of the proof.  Which is fair as continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets is a previously proven theorem.

I bring this up because in an ambushed situation where a person springs a "Quick!  What is an outline proof that a continuous function acheives a maximum value on a compact set" I'd immediate think that function being bounded as a more important and more subtle factor than that the function achieves the sumpremum at a point of the set.

But that was not the question.

You want an "intuitive proof" so although this is a proof by contradiction I'll modify it to a direct proof so we can "see" the point of maximum achievement.

So key points:

The supremum for $f(K)$ exists and is $M$.

Let $y$ be such $f(y) < M$. i.e. $y$ doesn't achieve maximum.

We can find $L_y$ so $f(y) < L_y < M$.

$f$ is continuous so there are $\delta_y$ for each $y$ so that $z \in B(y, \delta_y)$ means $f(z) < L_y < M$.

The $B(y, \delta_y)$s form an open cover for all the points that do not acheive maximum.

Take any finite subset of these $B(y, \delta_y)$
For any $z \in B(y_i, \delta_{y_i})$ means $f(z) < \max(L_{y_i})< M$ for the maximum of a finite values of $L_{y_i}$.

Thus $\max(L_{y_i}$ is an upperbound of the image of points in thes finite set of $B(y_i, \delta_{y_i})$.  But $\max(L_{y_i} < M$ so it isn't an upperbound of $f(K)$. So no finite subcover of $B(y, \delta_y)$ cover the compact $K$. So $B(y, \delta_y)$ can't be an open cover of $K$ and there must be so $y$ acheiving the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is that, assuming $f$ is bounded and the supremum is not attained (so the function has no maximum), then we can build an open cover of $X$ that has no finite subcover.

I believe that the proof by contradiction hides the main idea.

**Case 1: $f$ is upper bounded.**

Let $M=\sup\{f(x):x\in K\}$ and suppose $f(x)<M$, for every $x\in K$. Let $n>0$ be an integer. By definition of supremum, the set $A_n=f^{-1}\bigl((M-1/n,M)\bigr)$ is not empty. Set also $A_0=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,M-1/2)\bigr)$. Then
$$
K=\bigcup_{n\ge0}A_n
$$
so we have an open cover of $K$ that has no finite subcover.

**Case 2: $f$ is not upper bounded.**

For $n>0$, set $B_n=f^{-1}\bigl((n,\infty)\bigr)$ and $B_0=f^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,2)\bigr)$. Then $B_n$ is not empty, for $n>0$, and
$$
K=\bigcup_{n\ge0}B_n
$$
so we have an open cover of $K$ that has no finite subcover.