# Finiteness of the Injective Hull

Tags: general-topology, continuity, modules, compactness, injective-module

Please help me. I have read [Finiteness of the Injective Hull](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0070?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B390%5D%7D) by Alex Rosenberg and Daniel Zelinsky. An $R$-module $N$ has finite length if $N$ has a finite composition series. Alex Rosenberg and Daniel Zelinsky asked, "If $N$ has a finite length, does there exists an injective module containing $N$ which also has a finite length?".

In general topology, we have compact spaces, a generalization of finite spaces, and ([Why is compactness so important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485822/why-is-compactness-so-important)). This helps to understand the importance of compactness. My question is, "Why is finiteness so important for an injective hull?" Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: You read the paper, but did not find the author's motivation in the introduction persuasive?  I don't think it's that _finite composition length is important for injective hulls_ .  As the author says "every module has an injective hull... if the module is finite length, then is the injective hull finite length?"  Some things like this _are_ inherited by the injective hull. For example, the uniform dimensions of $M$ and $E(M)$ are the same.

Comment: _This problem was brought to the fore by Azumaya_ it says, while he was extending a notion to modules over an Artinian ring. Therefore, if you understand which modules have finite composition length hulls, then you might gain some benefit along the lines Azumaya was suggesting.